# Efficient and Consistent Timing in Swift (GCD)

Tags: swift, timer, background

A fitness application I'm working on for fun requires motion data to be appended to an array every 0.1 seconds, however, energy saving processes occurring when the application is backgrounded or the device is locked means that this accuracy drifts by up to a second.

I understand that a traditional timer often follows the outlined behaviour and therefore have been investigating alternative methods, specifically GCD timers. [A tutorial written on Medium](https://medium.com/@danielgalasko/a-background-repeating-timer-in-swift-412cecfd2ef9) explains one such method, however, I am unable to successfully execute the function(s).

I am running:

```
let t = RepeatingTimer(timeInterval: 0.1)
    t.eventHandler = {
        print("Timer Fired")
    }
    t.resume()
```

within my viewDidLoad function, but to no avail - no text is printed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {}
```

**My full code is as follows:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SystemConfiguration

class accelVController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       let t = RepeatingTimer(timeInterval: 0.1)
       t.eventHandler = {
          print("Timer Fired")
       }
       t.resume()
   }
}



/// RepeatingTimer mimics the API of DispatchSourceTimer but in a way that prevents
/// crashes that occur from calling resume multiple times on a timer that is
/// already resumed (noted by https://github.com/SiftScience/sift-ios/issues/52
class RepeatingTimer {

    let timeInterval: TimeInterval

    init(timeInterval: TimeInterval) {
        self.timeInterval = timeInterval
    }

    private lazy var timer: DispatchSourceTimer = {
        let t = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()
        t.schedule(deadline: .now() + self.timeInterval, repeating: self.timeInterval)
        t.setEventHandler(handler: { [weak self] in
            self?.eventHandler?()
        })
        return t
    }()

    var eventHandler: (() -> Void)?

    private enum State {
        case suspended
        case resumed
    }

    private var state: State = .suspended

    deinit {
        timer.setEventHandler {}
        timer.cancel()
        /*
         If the timer is suspended, calling cancel without resuming
         triggers a crash. This is documented here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15902
         */
        resume()
        eventHandler = nil
    }

    func resume() {
        if state == .resumed {
            return
        }
        state = .resumed
        timer.resume()
    }

    func suspend() {
        if state == .suspended {
            return
        }
        state = .suspended
        timer.suspend()
    }

}
```

If anyone could spare suggestions on improved methods of executing code consistently in the background, or can help me implement the code included I would be very grateful.

---

**Update:**
The app is essentially based around fall detection, although has location elements associated with it.

It is based around three arrays.

**Array a**: contains a timestamp, and whether the acceleration is lower than the minimum threshold (1), whether it is greater than the maximum threshold (2), or neither (0). It is essentially a register, and 2D - [[timestamp, status]]

**Array b**: is the result of looping through **array a** and looking for status values of 1. If this is found the timestamp of the element (only) is appended to the array (from **a** to **b**).

**Array c**: 's values are appended when a function that checks whether a time period of 2 seconds contains a 1, followed by a 2 (from **array b**). This is seen as a potential fall. A timestamp is appended only.

Array c is then looped through and looked at for periods of inactivity post-fall over the course of 3 seconds, which indicates unconsciousness and the need to send for help.

I appreciate this method may be inefficient, and not the best way of doing this, however, having little knowledge of Swift this seemed the most obvious to me, and works if backgrounding is not taken into consideration. I am more than happy to receive advice on more appropriate methods. The actions and methodology of noting a fall is [based off of this paper.](https://thesai.org/Downloads/Volume7No12/Paper_16-Automatic_Fall_Detection_using_Smartphone_Acceleration_Sensor.pdf)

My code as is can be [seen here](https://pastebin.com/9zYxPWYt). Apologies for the quantity of debugging prints.

Comment: FYI - A time interval of `0.1` is one tenth of a second or 100 milliseconds, not "0.1 milliseconds".

Comment: @rmaddy thanks - just an oversight in my description. Do you have any advice on implementing the repeatingTimer class?

Comment: "specifically GCD timers" A timer is a timer. You're not going to get away from the fact of how they work just because you call your timer by another name. NSTimer probably even uses GCD timer under the hood.

Comment: Also it's unclear (1) what problem you're trying to solve in the timer implementation you propose and (2) what problem you're trying to solve generally (maybe a timer is not the best way)

Comment: @matt thanks for your response. I have updated my question if you have the chance to take a look - I'm currently looking into the possibilities of utilising HealthKit.

Answer (score 3):

This is the wrong approach. Core Motion provides an efficient interface to the motion processor without your app having to constantly fire timers. Timers aren't going to be honored in the background, so this approach is not going to work in any case. You're seeing some drift over a short period of background activity, but if you give it a few more minutes you'll generally find that your app stops generating timer events entirely.

If what you want are the accelerometer events, set the `CMMotionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval` to what you want (0.1) and call `startAccelerometerUpdates(to:withHandler)` to handle the events. Don't forget to enable the "Background Mode: Location updates" in your app capabilities.

That said, you generally shouldn't try to manage a fitness app at the Core Motion layer. Apple provides much more powerful and high-level support through HealthKit's `HKWorkout`. HealthKit has, admittedly, an incredibly annoying API, but it ties you directly into the system that iOS is already using to track workouts, so you get a lot of features for free (particularly helping solve a lot of complicated filtering problems).

Comment: Right, this is what I meant in my comment about "what problem you're really trying to solve"... BTW "an incredibly annoying API" But tell us how you really feel about it :)

Comment: @matt, StackOverflow has "appropriate language" rules that prevent me from expressing my deep feelings about HealthKit, but it definitely is the right tool for a certain kinds of problems.

Comment: @RobNapier thank you for taking the time to help here, I have updated my question if you have the time to take a glance. I'll definitely have a look into HealthKit.

Comment: What you've described is definitely a job for Core Motion. You can't implement it with timers. Look at `userAcceleration`. It's probably going to give you precisely what you want (don't forget that gravity is a bias in the downward direction).  That said, for fall detection, rotationRate may be even more indicative of what you're looking for, and has already been pre-processed to remove gyroscopic biases. You can probably get away with much longer update periods as well, since Core Motion is already doing most of the analysis for you.

Comment: "and works if backgrounding is not taken into consideration." Exactly. You cannot solve the backgrounding issue the way you're going, and so you must go another way (which also happens to be a better way)

Comment: Hi @RobNapier, thanks for your help there. I've looked into Core Motion and agree that it can provide an uninterrupted stream of accelerometer information (such as this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_processed_device_motion_data#2875109). However, I'm unsure how this would help in terms of processing the data to ascertain whether there has been a fall or not further than my gatherAcc function. Would it be based around a queue, and reading those values from within the function itself, rather than creating another one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You'll still need to evaluate `userAcceleration` to look for falls, but that value has already been pre-processed to make it more accurate. Raw acceleration data can be incredibly noisy.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier, however, my original code relied upon multiple timers to check over these values, and I'm not sure how this would help remove the need for these as they are causing my original problem (drifting time). Although I can append the userAcceleration using this method, verifying whether there has been a fall every 2/3 seconds surely still requires the use of traditional timers? Essentially the method of checking the values is based upon time, I will look into using element identifiers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172854/discussion-between-george-and-rob-napier).